# Apache Spark Hadoop S3A SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

First time using Spark with S3A. I am getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error when accessing via hadoop S3A. However same works when I access S3 buckets using AWS SDK. Following is my code, I am not able to figure the error out. I believe there is something wrong in my settings.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            log.error("Usage: <app_name> <grok_pattern>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        final String appName = args[0];
        final SyslogParser syslogParser = new SyslogParser(args[1]);
        final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = initSparkContext(appName);
        final String queueName = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("SQS_QUEUE_NAME"))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("SQS_QUEUE_NAME required."));
        log.info("...started streaming {}", queueName);
        final ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(getQueueUrl(queueName))
                .withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
                .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        final ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = AMAZON_SQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
        log.info("...received new messages: {}", receiveMessageResult.getMessages().size());
        receiveMessageResult.getMessages()
                .stream()
                .map(Message::getBody)
                .map(Application::toJsonNode)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(Application::toS3Pair)
                .forEach(s3Pair -> processS3Object(s3Pair, syslogParser, sparkContext));
        sparkContext.close();
    }

    static SparkConf initSparkConf(String appName) {
        final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName(appName);
        conf.setMaster("local[*]");

        final EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider provider = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", provider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
        conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", provider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());
        // we are behind proxy hence set fs.s3a.proxy.host and port as well.
        return conf;
    }

    static JavaSparkContext initSparkContext(String appName) {
        final SparkConf conf = initSparkConf(appName);
        final JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        context.setLogLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG.name());
        return context;
    }

    static void processS3Object(final Pair<String, String> s3Pair, final SyslogParser syslogParser, final JavaSparkContext sparkContext) {
        final String outS3aUrl = "s3a://" + s3Pair.getLeft() + "/out/" + s3Pair.getRight();
        final String inS3aUrl = "s3a://" + s3Pair.getLeft() + "/" + s3Pair.getRight();
        sparkContext.textFile(inS3aUrl)
                .saveAsTextFile(outS3aUrl);

    }
```

Following the DEBUG log and it shows the Signature is not matching, however I did notice the date sent to AWS is different from my system date. Not sure if that is the issue, if yes not sure how to change it.

```
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG AWS4Signer: AWS4 Canonical Request: '"GET
/asdasd/asdasd.json

amz-sdk-invocation-id:b14a016a-a589-b314-536a-a19ad9e3a65c
amz-sdk-request:attempt=14;max=21
amz-sdk-retry:13/19092/372
content-type:application/octet-stream
host:temp-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
if-match:1f0aa30fff75c3b01269bf3a7e7ad241
range:bytes=0-284846
user-agent:Hadoop 3.3.1, aws-sdk-java/1.12.112 Linux/5.4.0-90-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.13.5 vendor/Private_Build cfg/retry-mode/legacy
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20211122T010938Z

amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;content-type;host;if-match;range;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG AWS4Signer: AWS4 String to Sign: '"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20211122T010938Z
20211122/ap-southeast-2/s3/aws4_request
8a5536b64079a96c3bbb61492d7fb2232f83b0546dcb91cbca8125a182927813"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG RequestAddCookies: CookieSpec selected: default
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG RequestAuthCache: Auth cache not set in the context
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://proxy:3228->https://temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443][total available: 2; route allocated: 1 of 48; total allocated: 2 of 48]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-7 << "end of stream"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-7: Close connection
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection leased: [id: 8][route: {tls}->http://proxy:3128->https://temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443][total available: 1; route allocated: 1 of 48; total allocated: 2 of 48]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG MainClientExec: Opening connection {tls}->http://proxy:3128->https://temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator: Connecting to proxy/10.1.1.1:3128
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator: Connection established 10.1.1.2:38250<->10.1.1.1:3128
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> CONNECT temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 HTTP/1.1
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Host: temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_292)
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "CONNECT temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Host: temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_292)[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "[\r][\n]"

21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG MainClientExec: Tunnel to target created.
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: socket.getSupportedProtocols(): [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello], socket.getEnabledProtocols(): [TLSv1.2]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: TLS protocol enabled for SSL handshake: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: Starting handshake
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory: Secure session established
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory:  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory:  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory:  peer principal: CN=*.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory:  peer alternative names: [s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, s3.dualstack.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3.dualstack.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3.amazonaws.com, *.s3-control.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, s3-control.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3-control.dualstack.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, s3-control.dualstack.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3-accesspoint.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3-accesspoint.dualstack.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com, *.s3.ap-southeast-2.vpce.amazonaws.com]
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG SdkTLSSocketFactory:  issuer principal: CN=pan-d84ofw002-CA
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-8: set socket timeout to 200000
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG MainClientExec: Executing request GET /folder/filename.json HTTP/1.1
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> GET /folder/filename.json HTTP/1.1
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Host: temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> amz-sdk-invocation-id: b14a016a-a589-b314-536a-a19ad9e3a65c
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> amz-sdk-request: attempt=14;max=21
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> amz-sdk-retry: 13/19092/372
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AWSACCESSKEY/20211122/ap-southeast-2/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;content-type;host;if-match;range;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=72cd72ef9948643604f7ccd460f29cdfa912f1fdde0faa913f84a4425dd43
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> If-Match: 1f0aa30fff75c3b01269bf3a7e7ad241
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Range: bytes=0-284846
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> User-Agent: Hadoop 3.3.1, aws-sdk-java/1.12.112 Linux/5.4.0-90-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.13.5 vendor/Private_Build cfg/retry-mode/legacy
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> X-Amz-Date: 20211122T010938Z
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Content-Length: 0
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "GET /folder/filename.json HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Host: temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "amz-sdk-invocation-id: b14a016a-a589-b314-536a-a19ad9e3a65c[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "amz-sdk-request: attempt=14;max=21[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "amz-sdk-retry: 13/19092/372[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AWSACCESSKEY/20211122/ap-southeast-2/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;content-type;host;if-match;range;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=72cd72ef9948643604f7ccd460f29cdfa912f1fdde0faa913f84a4425dd43[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "If-Match: 1f0aa30fff75c3b01269bf3a7e7ad241[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Range: bytes=0-284846[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "User-Agent: Hadoop 3.3.1, aws-sdk-java/1.12.112 Linux/5.4.0-90-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.13.5 vendor/Private_Build cfg/retry-mode/legacy[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "X-Amz-Date: 20211122T010938Z[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:38 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 >> "[\r][\n]"

21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "x-amz-request-id: 03D8MX920R4B7Q3Y[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "x-amz-id-2: PIOL/VOfyuExRB2FLPovEO104N66SQfe+fx3nCLlD5k51KsOe7m3un6LJUO+9UNCsWEMB/ydGeo=[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 01:09:38 GMT[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "Server: AmazonS3[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "Content-Type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "1036[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << x-amz-request-id: 03D8MX920R4B7Q3Y
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << x-amz-id-2: PIOL/VOfyuExRB2FLPovEO104N66SQfe+fx3nCLlD5k51KsOe7m3un6LJUO+9UNCsWEMB/ydGeo=
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 01:09:38 GMT
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << Server: AmazonS3
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << Content-Type: application/xml
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG headers: http-outgoing-8 << Connection: keep-alive
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG MainClientExec: Connection can be kept alive for 60000 MILLISECONDS
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG ClockSkewAdjuster: Reported server date (from 'Date' header): Mon, 22 Nov 2021 01:09:38 GMT
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AWSACCESSKEY</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "20211122T010938Z[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "20211122/ap-southeast-2/s3/aws4_request[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "63ed1dbeae3d1146f51197796c4d3a76736601e30444c91aa306d186426a15ea</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>72cd72ef9948643604f7ccd460f29cdfa912f1fdde0faa913f84a4425dd43</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 31 31 31 32 32 54 30 31 30 39 33 38 5a 0a 32 30 32 31 31 31 32 32 2f 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 36 33 65 64 31 64 62 65 61 65 33 64 31 31 34 36 66 35 31 31 39 37 37 39 36 63 34 64 33 61 37 36 37 33 36 36 30 31 65 33 30 34 34 34 63 39 31 61 61 33 30 36 64 31 38 36 34 32 36 61 31 35 65 61</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>GET[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "/folder/filename.json[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "amz-sdk-invocation-id:b14a016a-a589-b314-536a-a19ad9e3a65c[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "amz-sdk-request:attempt=14;max=21[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "amz-sdk-retry:13/19092/372[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "content-type:application/octet-stream[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "host:temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "if-match:1f0aa30fff75c3b01269bf3a7e7ad241[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "range:[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "user-agent:Hadoop 3.3.1, aws-sdk-java/1.12.112 Linux/5.4.0-90-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.292-b10 java/1.8.0_292 scala/2.13.5 vendor/Private_Build cfg/retry-mode/legacy[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "x-amz-date:20211122T010938Z[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;content-type;host;if-match;range;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date[\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 37 6e 65 77 73 2f 65 61 61 38 30 39 64 61 32 31 38 63 37 63 39 32 34 61 31 34 37 37 35 38 31 63 61 39 36 35 39 38 65 62 63 64 38 36 32 33 61 63 63 65 36 36 37 30 64 37 36 31 34 34 30 31 62 33 38 39 62 66 39 30 2e 6a 73 6f 6e 0a 0a 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 69 6e 76 6f 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2d 69 64 3a 62 31 34 61 30 31 36 61 2d 61 35 38 39 2d 62 33 31 34 2d 35 33 36 61 2d 61 31 39 61 64 39 65 33 61 36 35 63 0a 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 3a 61 74 74 65 6d 70 74 3d 31 34 3b 6d 61 78 3d 32 31 0a 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 72 65 74 72 79 3a 31 33 2f 31 39 30 39 32 2f 33 37 32 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6f 63 74 65 74 2d 73 74 72 65 61 6d 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 70 72 6f 64 2d 69 63 65 70 69 63 2d 72 61 77 32 70 61 63 73 2e 73 33 2e 61 70 2d 73 6f 75 74 68 65 61 73 74 2d 32 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 69 66 2d 6d 61 74 63 68 3a 31 66 30 61 61 33 30 66 66 66 37 35 63 33 62 30 31 32 36 39 62 66 33 61 37 65 37 61 64 32 34 31 0a 72 61 6e 67 65 3a 0a 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a 48 61 64 6f 6f 70 20 33 2e 33 2e 31 2c 20 61 77 73 2d 73 64 6b 2d 6a 61 76 61 2f 31 2e 31 32 2e 31 31 32 20 4c 69 6e 75 78 2f 35 2e 34 2e 30 2d 39 30 2d 67 65 6e 65 72 69 63 20 4f 70 65 6e 4a 44 4b 5f 36 34 2d 42 69 74 5f 53 65 72 76 65 72 5f 56 4d 2f 32 35 2e 32 39 32 2d 62 31 30 20 6a 61 76 61 2f 31 2e 38 2e 30 5f 32 39 32 20 73 63 61 6c 61 2f 32 2e 31 33 2e 35 20 76 65 6e 64 6f 72 2f 50 72 69 76 61 74 65 5f 42 75 69 6c 64 20 63 66 67 2f 72 65 74 72 79 2d 6d 6f 64 65 2f 6c 65 67 61 63 79 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3a 32 30 32 31 31 31 32 32 54 30 31 30 39 33 38 5a 0a 0a 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 69 6e 76 6f 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2d 69 64 3b 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 3b 61 6d 7a 2d 73 64 6b 2d 72 65 74 72 79 3b 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3b 68 6f 73 74 3b 69 66 2d 6d 61 74 63 68 3b 72 61 6e 67 65 3b 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 73 68 61 32 35 36 3b 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>03D8MX920R4B7Q3Y</RequestId><HostId>PIOL/VOfyuExRB2FLPovEO104N66SQfe+fx3nCL"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "lD5k51KsOe7m3un6LJUO+9UNCsWEMB/ydGeo=</HostId></Error>"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "0[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG wire: http-outgoing-8 << "[\r][\n]"
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection [id: 8][route: {tls}->http://proxy:3128->https://temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443] can be kept alive for 60.0 seconds
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-8: set socket timeout to 0
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: Connection released: [id: 8][route: {tls}->http://proxy:3128->https://temp-buckets.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443][total available: 2; route allocated: 1 of 48; total allocated: 2 of 48]
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG request: Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 03D8MX920R4B7Q3Y; S3 Extended Request ID: PIOL/VOfyuExRB2FLPovEO104N66SQfe+fx3nCLlD5k51KsOe7m3un6LJUO+9UNCsWEMB/ydGeo=; Proxy: proxy), S3 Extended Request ID: PIOL/VOfyuExRB2FLPovEO104N66SQfe+fx3nCLlD5k51KsOe7m3un6LJUO+9UNCsWEMB/ydGeo=
21/11/22 12:09:39 DEBUG ClockSkewAdjuster: Reported server date (from 'Date' header): Mon, 22 Nov 2021 01:09:38 GMT
```

**UPDATES**

After @stevel comments, confirmed the properties with the hadoop documentation and updated the code. Still getting the same issue.

We keep trying to figure the issue out, may be its because of the corporate proxy. Will update once I resolve this issue.

Stacktrace after changes

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: D26Z2QHKMBK110Q5; S3 Extended Request ID: 9MZ5uIB1P6HUEaBWrIqkxfUm8ftWPclkkQ8EFOffsWacj3Ki6U6koSmHt3d55n/ItS34bmUGU3I=; Proxy: jailbird.cp.pacs), S3 Extended Request ID: 9MZ5uIB1P6HUEaBWrIqkxfUm8ftWPclkkQ8EFOffsWacj3Ki6U6koSmHt3d55n/ItS34bmUGU3I=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1828)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1412)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1374)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5227)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5173)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lambda$reopen$0(S3AInputStream.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:115)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: where in the hadoop s3a documentation is the "fs.s3a.signatureVersion` covered -and it is just something you picked up from other SO posts, have you considered looking at the hadoop s3a docs first?
As one of the main S3A authors, its a losing battle against people who don't read it or the troubleshooting page, and instead just copy broken SO code and then ask for help. downvoting due to a lack of due diligence.

Comment: Thanks @stevel. Yes you are correct. I have removed the properties and just set the aws credentials and proxies. Confirming them with the documentation. Still getting 
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Answer (score 0):

The same code works directly on AWS EMR cluster. I believe it the corporate firewall which was blocking my AWS calls. Hence, not an issue anymore.